How Does a 95% Energy Reduction in Neural Networks Affect Accuracy and Efficiency?
Earlier this month, a fascinating paper was published on arXiv:
"Addition is All You Need for Energy-efficient Language Models"
The authors propose an algorithm, $\mathcal{L}\text{-Mul}$, which claims to reduce energy usage by up to 95% for elementwise floating-point (FP) tensor multiplications and 80% for dot products. The key innovation is an approximation of FP multiplication using integer additions, potentially maintaining nearly the same model accuracy while drastically improving efficiency
On the face of it, this seems like it could be a groundbreaking discovery.
Traditionally, FP arithmetic involves multiplying the mantissas of two floating-point numbers, which has quadratic complexity ($O(m^2)$, where $m$ is the number of bits in the mantissa). This is often a computational bottleneck. $\mathcal{L}\text{-Mul}$ approximates this mantissa multiplication using linear combinations of additions, reducing the complexity to $O(m)$, thus optimising both time efficiency and power consumption.
A few issues occured to me while reading this paper:

The precision comparisons are only made against fp8 formats, but energy savings are compared against larger formats like fp16 and fp32, which seems inconsistent. To clarify, fp8 (8-bit floating-point), fp16 (16-bit floating-point), and fp32 (32-bit floating-point) represent different levels of numerical precision in floating-point formats, with fp8 offering the least precision and fp32 the most. The lower the bit-size (eg., fp8), the fewer bits are used to store the number, which can reduce memory and computational demands but at the cost of precision. Comparing energy savings from $\mathcal{L}\text{-Mul}$ against fp16 and fp32 - which inherently use more bits and power - may give an unfairly optimistic view of the energy efficiency, as the algorithm operates at a lower precision. Ideally, both precision and energy should be compared on a consistent level to avoid misleading conclusions.

The paper lacks large-scale tests or real-world deployments, leaving most of the claims to be theoretical.

There are many spelling and grammar errors that detract from a professional tone, giving the impression of a rushed release. I get that the authors are probably not native speakers of English, however even a cursory proofread would have caught most of them.

The paper contains quite a lot of spelling and grammar errors, which detract from its readability and professionalism. It gives the impression of being rushed, which is unusual for a technical preprint that aims to introduce a major breakthrough. Careful proofreading would strengthen the paper.

The experiments appear to lack large-scale tests or real-world deployment results. Given the ambitious claims of reduced energy consumption, a large-scale, real-world evaluation would lend credibility to the method. Current evaluations are limited to benchmarks rather than large deployment settings where power consumption would be more crucial.

The method remains theoretical in terms of hardware efficiency. While it shows promise in software simulations, hardware-level implementation is necessary to confirm the energy savings. Without this, the energy reduction claims may not fully translate into practice.


I also thought it was quite interesting that both authors work for a company, not a University: BitEnergy AI: https://bitenergy.ai/
OK, so finally:
How Does a 95% Energy Reduction in Neural Networks Affect Accuracy and Efficiency?
